# Horizontal scroll when rotate UIColectionView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build a `collectionView` in swift, I want that when the device is in portrait the `collectionView` scrolls vertically while when I rotate the device in landscape mode the `collectionView` scrolls horizontally. This is the `CollectionView` class:

```
class SceneBuilderVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet var collection: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool{
       return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int{
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw())
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return 50;
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell!{
        var cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return cell
    }
}
```

To change the scroll direction I need to change the `collectionView` layout.

```
var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
var scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
flowLayout.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
self.collection.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Also, with iOS8, Apple change the screen rotating method **`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration`** with **`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator`**

How can I use the **`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator`* method to check when the device rotate and as a consequence changing the scroll direction?

Answer (score 3):

Use the completion handler in animateAlongsideTransition to check the orientation after the rotation and make any adjustments.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: {context in
        if(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait || UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown){
            //this is portrait (or upsidedown), do something
        }else{
            //landscape 
        }
    })
}
```

But unless in special cases, you shouldn't really care what the exact orientation the device is in, you can simply adjust your view to the "new size"

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1:**

If your collection view occupies whole screen then you can simply check if width is more than height and take the result as landscape orientation.

**Option #2:**

Or you can use function:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)
```

But you should be aware that `interfaceOrientation` property got deprecated in iOS8.

Comment: if I use the option 1, where I have to check it? because there isn't a function which gets recalled every time that the device changes orientation.

Comment: Examine `size` property in `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`.

Comment: `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` gets called every time device rotates. But it does not get called during initial load of view, so you should do it manually in `viewDidLoad`(or any other suitable method).

Answer (score 0):

Thats the complete function:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator   coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator!){
    if let theAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication() {
        let orientation = theAppDelegate.statusBarOrientation
        if orientation.isPortrait {
            println("Landscape")
            var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            //flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
            //flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(80, 80)
            var scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
            self.collection.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
        }else{
            println("Protrait")
            var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            // flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
            //flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(80, 80)
            var scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = scrollDirection
            self.collection.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work: the status bar's orientation is BEFORE the orientation change happens... and you don't know if the change is 90 or 180 degrees or something else. So this won't work. Per http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/08/06/ios8-day-by-day-day-14-rotation-deprecation, I think you have to look at the targetTransform() on the coordinator.